# reactJS - useEffect() empty response using Axios GET request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, axios

This is where I'm trying to get data from back-end, using Axios requests:

```js
 const [models, setModels] = useState([]);

const sponsor_id = localStorage.getItem('sponsor_id');
 
  useEffect(() => {
        api.get('models', { sponsor_id }).then(response => {
            setModels(response.data);
        });
    }, []);
```

And this is my back-end, where it was supposed to return data from database:

```js
module.exports = {
    async index(request, response) {
        const { sponsor_id } = request.body;

        const models = await connection('model').select('*').where('sponsor_id', sponsor_id);

        return response.json(models);
    },
```

But the response on front-end is empty. It was supposed to return some data. I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: Where is `api` inside the `useEffect` coming from?  Can you show that object to get a better idea of what you're trying to do?

Comment: It's coming from: import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3333',
})

export default api;

Comment: So on my front-end file, I imported 'api' from '/services/api.js', that contains the code above.

Comment: Ok...one thing is that you shouldn't send anything on the request body with a `GET` request.  I would suggest you send it to the server as a parameter on the url instead of trying to send it on the request body.

Comment: I also tried send as request.params, but it doesn't work either. The message returned from Node server is: "query: select * from 'model' where `sponsor_id` = ?", but the sponsor_id is on the localStorage, I already tested with console.log(). I think the problem is with useEffect().

Comment: I just tried use with headers.authorization and it worked. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Sweet, glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this example. Here I call axios in useEffect and showing response data in ui.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

function PostListPage() {
    const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
    let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

    useEffect(() => {
        let isSubscribed = true;
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
            .then(res => {
                const posts = res.data;
                setPost(posts);

            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
        return function cleanup() {
            isSubscribed = false;
            signal.cancel('Api is being canceled');
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ul>
                {
                    posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>)
                }
            </ul>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default PostListPage;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I resolved the problem using the header instead the body of the request.